# Concurrent Futures and the correct number of threads to use.

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I'm developing a webscraping tool and I am using concurrent processes. I want to know if there is a general rule for the number of threads you need to use. Currently, I have it set for 10, but I've noticed that I get a lot more missing data values when I push the number past the amount of threads.

```
URLs = loadit()
start = time.time()
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    # start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url): url for url in URLs}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
            print(data.values())
            # scraped_data = restaurant_parse(link)
            # time.sleep(random.randrange(3, 5))
            writeit(outName, data.values())
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

lscpu on a ubuntu linux box shows

```
ubuntu-dev@ubuntu:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                3
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-2
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    3
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 61
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5557U CPU @ 3.10GHz
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               3100.000
BogoMIPS:              6200.00
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-2
```

Thank you!

Comment: "but I've noticed that I get a lot more missing data values when I push the number past the amount of threads."  - then you probably have a bug and/or a race condition....

Comment: Are you scraping all of this data from the same domain? What errors are thrown? Are you saturating your network link?

Comment: all status codes are 200 but come from the same domain, so that shouldnt be the issue. However, it is a LOT of data, which I know can cause issues with concurrent futures. When I start the process, my cpu spikes to 100 percent for the duration. Also, yes, the NIC is being saturated because it is a 4G usb puck. So, I know that severely bottlenecks my scraping.

Comment: @MitchWheat, after spending some more time with it, I think there is some validity to your race condition comment. Thank you.

Comment: The errors were unrelated. The place that I am scraping the data from is very tricky with the data on the page. Often times, I have to make multiple requests to the same site to grab the text. If I said where I was scraping from, it would make more sense.